# Saving Interpolation data in a shapefile as an alternate to Raster Output

Tags: qgis

Is there a possibility that we store our interpolation data in a shapefile instead of a raster image, so that the shapefile can be used to display the Interpolation as a replacement to the RASTER OUTPUT.

Also I intend to use such a shapefile in a HTML webpage with hover effects, so that if a hovers the mouse over some points, they can see the value at the location in a pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways to represent interpolation results in vector.

The first methos is to buil a TIN directly when you interpolate. I'm not sure the hover will work fine on a simple html because the value of the TIN needs to be interpolated on the fly.

The second method is to build a set of points at the center of each raster cell ([see here for example](http://fr.slideshare.net/shencoop/qgis-raster-to-point)). However, this is a very inefficient method to store this kind of information.

Comment: with TIN method, I am still not able to get my output for interpolation in shapefile Format.
The second method's output I guess would not be as smooth in appearance.

Comment: you can convert the TIN to triangle polygons for storage in a shapefile (ideally in 3 D shapefile, otherwise you can only store the average value of each face). The second method will be as smooth as a raster if the symbol for each point have the size of the cells.